# Ionic Capacitor app give me lots of errors

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm on Windows 10 and I've created a Ionic 5.0.7 app with Capacitor 2.0.0.

I use this command to build app:

```
ionic build
```

After, I use this command:

```
npx cap sync
```

And, to finish, I use this command to open Android Studio:

```
npx cap open android
```

The first problem come during building on Android Studio:

> org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create
>   an instance of type
>   com.novoda.release.internal.compat.gradle5_3.AndroidSoftwareComponentCompat_Gradle_5_3.
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create 
>   an instance of type
>   com.novoda.release.internal.compat.gradle5_3.AndroidSoftwareComponentCompat_Gradle_5_3.

And...

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/gradle/api/internal/java/usagecontext/LazyConfigurationUsageContext
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/gradle/api/internal/java/usagecontext/LazyConfigurationUsageContext

I've other random errors... It's weird...

Answer (score 22):

### Update

Check  @Carl Pool 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62096477/1427338) 
They fixed it in the new capacitor Version, no need to downgrade anymore

### Old Answer

To fix this downgrade Gradle and Gradle plugin in Android Studio.

File -> Project Structure -> Project

If you keep the plugin to 4.0.0 it will require a minimum Gradle version of 6 so put it back to a lower version like 3.6.3

Version 6 of Gradle does not support LazyConfigurationUsageContext as mentionened by @NishaBhat, so use 5.6.4 instead.

This issue currently has a ticket on Github:
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3003

[image]

Comment: any idea on when they re going to fix this? So we dont have to do a  work around? I run Canary version of Android Studio

Comment: @sasysolutions the fix is now live in version 2.1.2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62096477/3550988

Answer (score 20):

This issue has been resolved in Capacitor version `2.1.2`.

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3003

Please update the Capacitor dependencies in package.json to version `2.1.2` and then in Android Studio click the button to sync the project with Gradle.

```
"@capacitor/android": "^2.1.2",
"@capacitor/core": "2.1.2",
```

Comment: This must be the Solution now. I hope you'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Switch to using gradle version 5.6.4. That did the trick for me. LazyConfigurationUsageContext doesn't have support in gradle versions 6.0+

Answer (score 2):

I was getting an error

`Cause: org/gradle/api/internal/java/usagecontext/LazyConfigurationUsageContext`

I solved by downgraded distributionUrl(`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`) to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`

it will give an error if above 6+

Answer (score 1):

Same problem.. had many issues:

Errors and how I solved:

Error 1. Gradle sync failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
                 Solution - Downloaded the zip file and stored in on my local in the \android\gradle\wrapper folder.
Updated the distribution URL to: distributionUrl=./gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

Error 2. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError & java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Solution - Downloaded Gradle version 5.6.4 and updated the environment variables.

Error 3. Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3

Updated as per the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have not downgraded the gradle version `6.1.1` But what i did is that:

I removed these lines from `build.gradle` file
`apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'` &
 `classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.1'`

The Issue just gone like Boom !!

I think this Bintray Dependencies just conflicting behind the scene.